# Delete a line in txt file after a specific keyword

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a txt file like:

```
sample text1  
sample text2  
sample text3
```

and I need it to be:

```
sample  
sample  
sample
```

Basically, I need to delete the entire line after a given phrase, in this case the "`sample`" keyword

Can someone help me?  I would prefer vbscript or something that is stanalone and I can make a batch for this

Regards,

Comment: Does every line always start with "sample"? Or can it be somewhere in the text?

Comment: No, it can be anywhere in the line

Comment: Do you want to check line by line?

Comment: yes, line by line, the previous powershell solution all worked, but I would prefer in VBSCRIPT:)

Comment: Hope this will work for you!!

Answer (score 2):

(Get-Content sample.txt) -replace '.*sample(.+)', '$1' | Out-File sample.txt

Comment: Ooops, just realized that what you want to keep is the beginning of each line. So, this should be: (Get-Content sample.txt) -replace '(.*sample).+', '$1' | Out-File sample.txt

Answer (score 0):

This will work inside a .cmd or .bat file:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('type file1') do @echo %i >> file2
```

Comment: Hi, that is working quite well except one thing, I don't always have the same delimiters. I need one script that will strictly search only for a keyword within a line and strips the rest of the line after that word.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with powershell, I'll give you a solution in powershell:

```
$target='sample'
foreach ($line in gc .\foo.txt){$line.substring(0,$target.length)|out-file -append bar.txt}
```

I assume that every line starts with "sample".

If the "sample" text is anywhere in the line, this should work:

```
$target='sample'
foreach ($line in gc .\foo.txt){$line.substring(0,$line.indexof($target)+$target.length)|out-file -append bar.txt}
```

Comment: the problem is that the keyword can be anywhere on the line, if it was the first your script was perfect

Comment: Added a second version, it now should work with the pattern anywhere in the line

Answer (score 0):

With Just Vbscript, you can achieve this as follows

```
Option Explicit 
Dim oFSO, oTxtFile, sLine  ,filePath, cTxtFile
Const ForReading=1
Const ForWriting=2

filePath ="C:\Documents and Settings\Amol\Desktop\Converted\test.txt"
'' Filepath is your local path to txt file
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oTxtFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1) 
Set cTxtFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(filePath & ".tmp")

Do Until oTxtFile.AtEndOfStream 

  sLine = oTxtFile.ReadLine
  If InStr(sLine,"sample") <> 0 Then
     sLine =  Left(sLine, InStr(sLine,"sample") -1 )&"sample" 
     cTxtFile.WriteLine(sLine)
  End if 

Loop 
oTxtFile.Close
cTxtFile.Close
oFSO.DeleteFile(filePath)
oFSO.MoveFile filePath&".tmp", filePath
```